# "There was a problem reaching this app" error in the Lists app, on the web version of Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I (the owner of the channel) added a Lists tab to the Channel. It works fine when I view it in the browser. For one member, when he uses the web version of Teams, this tab refuses to load. It displays "There was a problem reaching this app". It works fine when he views this on the phone.
How can he fix this issue?

Comment: Could you please share the repro steps and sample code so that we can check it from our end?

Comment: Sorry, what sample code? I'm referring to the MSFT "Lists" app. I'm trying to add it in a channel.

Comment: @md1000 - We tried to repro the issue as you mentioned adding 'Lists' app in channel as owner of the team and it loads fine for both owner and member of that Team  in Teams desktop client as well as in Web client. No deviations encountered. Please try to update/restart Teams version and check if it helps. Thanks!

Comment: I dont know what you want me to update. I am using Teams from the Browser (Microsoft Edge). If you tell me how, I can provide you with a TraceIdentifier or something which you can use to check your logs what the issue is.

Comment: Please share console logs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/developer-tools

Comment: Hello. No, the issue isn't resolved - but the user facing the issue hasn't come back to me with the console logs. You can close this issue - I will re-open when I get the console logs from the user.